# Developing for iPhone / Syncing the iPhone to another Computer than Dev?

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch

Weird question: I have an iPod Touch and plan to get an iPhone once the next generation comes out.

Now, my main machine is a Windows PC which is where the iPod is connected to. As I need a Mac to do development, I wonder if it is possible to connect the iPod to the Mac for Xcode/Development but keep it synced to Windows for Syncing?

Not sure if this belongs here or on SuperUser though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as long as you don't set up your iPod to sync with OS X iTunes, you will be able to develop with the iPod in OS X and still keep it syncing with iTunes on Windows (it's what I do with my phone).